# Can we see that the Hopf map is essential without using Hurewicz?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, math-history, fiber-bundles, hopf-fibration

The Hopf map is the projection of a circle bundle $h\colon S^3 \to \mathbb{CP}^1 \cong S^2$, where the complex numbers of unit length $S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$ act on the unit vectors $S^3 \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ by scaling. I am interested in an elementary argument (in particular not using the Hurewicz theorem) showing that this map is essential, or in other words not null-homotopic, and I'm also wondering what were the original techniques to prove this.

I know the Hopf map is essential by considering the long exact sequence of homotopy groups for a fibration. Since $S^1$'s universal cover is contractible $\pi_k(S^1)\cong 0$ for $k > 1$ so there are isomorphisms $\pi_k(h)\colon \pi_k(S^3) \cong \pi_k(S^2)$ for $k > 2$, and since $\pi_3(S^3)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ that means $\pi_3(h)$ is non-zero. However, the only reason I know that $\pi_3(S^3)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ is from the Hurewicz theorem, which is far from elementary. (Note however that this sequence does establish the result that $\pi_2(S^2) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ without using Hurewicz.)

Is there a different approach to showing the Hopf map is essential, which doesn't rely on a computation of $\pi_3(S^3)$? Alternatively, it would suffice to have an elementary way of proving that $\pi_3(S^3) \neq 0$ (without necessarily determining the actual value), since this is the only property I needed to deduce $\pi_3(h)\neq 0$.

---

More generally I guess I am interested in the history of higher homotopy groups. From what I understand people initially thought that *all higher homotopy groups were trivial* and I get the impression that the Hopf map was one of the early non-trivial examples. I want to know what were the first non-trivial examples and what were the techniques used, and how much of it depended on difficult results like Hurewicz. (I apologize that this is maybe not the correct forum for math history questions, but I'm not aware of a better one.)

Comment: It occurs to me that it's kind of trivial to show $\pi_n(S^n)\neq 0$ by using the fact that homology is a homotopy-invariant functor. If we consider $id\colon S^n \to S^n$ then by functoriality $H_n(id) = id_{H_n(S^n)} \cong id_{\mathbb{Z}}$ (as long as $n\geq 1$) and so it cannot be null-homotopic by homotopy-invariance.

Comment: Using the property of a fibration, if the projection is nullhomotopic we can deform the total space into the fiber over the basepoint. So if this map were nullhomotopic, we could deform $S^3$ so that it misses a point, so we can further deform it into a point. But of course $S^3$ is not contractible from homology.

Comment: Ah, I think I see. Just to slightly rephrase so I'm sure I understand, if $h\circ id \colon S^3 \to S^2$ is null-homotopic we can lift a null-homotopy to show that $id$ is homotopic to a non-surjective map (in particular one whose image is an $S^1$ orbit) and hence is null-homotopic, which like you say contradicts homology computations.

Comment: @ConnorMalin I guess this generalizes to saying that if $p\colon S^n \to X$ is any Serre fibration and $|X| > 1$ then $p$ is not null-homotopic.

Comment: Slightly more can be said. The map $p$ must be nontrivial on homotopy groups. Otherwise the inclusion of the fiber would be a weak homotopy equivalence, but for any nontrivial fibration the inclusion of the fiber into $S^n$ will be nullhomotopic.

Comment: Another way is to notice that the cofiber of the Hopf map $\mathbb{C}P^2$ has a non-trivial cup product which prevents it from being homotopy equivalent to $S^2\vee S^4$. As far as I know this calculation can be done with algebro-geometric methods that make no reference whatsoever to any properties of $S^3$.

Comment: In terms of history I have heard that people thought that higher homotopy groups were "trivial" in the sense that they were uninteresting, not that they gave the trivial group. Because they were abelian people initially thought that they couldn't be the right generalization of the fundamental group.